# Test of irreducibility of a binary polynomial

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

What criteria do we have to efficiently test if a binary polynomial $P(x)$ is irreducible?

Assume $P$ is given as a vector of $n+1$ bits $c_i$, with $c_0=c_n=1$, as $P(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^nc_j\,x^j$ .

---

If $P(x)$ is irreducible, then $x^{2^n-1}\bmod P=1$ (proof: the order of $x$ in the multiplicative group modulo $x$ divides the group order). This can give a quick and certain indication that a polynomial is *not* irreducible (the test runs in $O(n^3)$ binary operations using $O(n)$ bits of memory with classical algorithms).

Unfortunately, much like the Fermat pseudo-prime test to base 2 has pseudoprimes ([OEIS A001567](https://oeis.org/A001567)), there are pseudo-primitives to this test. The list to degree 9 inclusive is (not yet at OEIS but soon to become [A316970](https://oeis.org/A316970)):
$$\begin{array}{l}
1+x+x^4+x^6\\
1+x^2+x^5+x^6\\
1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6\\
1+x+x^2+x^4+x^8\\
1+x+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^7+x^8\\
1+x^4+x^6+x^7+x^8\\
\dots\end{array}$$

How can we make a more selective test? Is there an analog to the strong pseudoprime test?

Update: found the related [*Rabin's test for polynomial irreducibility over $\Bbb F_2$*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528552/35016)

Comment: Isn't testing for non-trivial common divisors, $\gcd(P(x),x^{2^m}-x)$, $m<\deg P(x)$, a viable option? The first step in the Euclidean algorithm calls for the remainder of $x^{2^m}-x$ modulo $P(x)$. This can be done efficiently with square-and-multiply (and the result can be reused when you increment $m$). From that point on you only have "low" degree polynomials, so Euclid runs fast.

Comment: Maybe this article has something helpful? [On the number of irreducible polynomials
with 0,1 coefficients](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa88/aa8844.pdf)